# Display automatic row height adjustment. XLSXWRITER (python)

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

How to display automatic row height adjustment?
I tried with using 'text_wrap': True , but doesn't work for me. Also , I doen't want to set_row() statically beacuse the data is dynamic.

This is the option in Excel which I want .

[image]

For example:

```
 cell_format = workbook.add_format()
            cell_format.set_text_wrap()

            sheet.write(2, 0, "Some long text to wrap in a cell Some long text to wrap in a cell Some long text to wrap in a cell Some long text to wrap in a cell Some long text to wrap in a cell Some long text to wrap in a cell", cell_format)
            sheet.write(4, 0, "It's\na bum\nwrapIt's\na bum\nwrapIt's\na bum\nwrapIt's\na bum\nwrapIt's\na bum\nwrapIt's\na bum\nwrapIt's\na bum\nwrap ", cell_format)
```

This is the output of text_wrap

[image]

which I need is that :
[image]

Any help please?

Thanks .

Comment: [Xlsxwriter documentation](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/format.html#set_text_wrap) explains how to use `text wrap`

Comment: @moken ; I edited the post with an example . Thanks.

Comment: What application is the screenshots from?  Can you try the output file in Excel.